# can't set member variable as object reference

Tags: c++, object, reference

in my class i have a private member like this: ISymbolFactory& mSymbolFactory;

then i have a SetFactory method which has ISymbolFactory& as a parameter.

If i want to set mSymbolFactory to another object (Which is implemented as **singelton**)  can do this only one time. if i want to overwrite the membervariable, then it won't get it right.
it will stuck on the **first** object i set to this variable.

the member method is called like this: SetFactory(SomeFactory::GetInstance());

class:

```
class SymbolParser: public Object {
private:
    ISymbolFactory& mSymbolFactory;
public:
    SymbolParser();
    ~SymbolParser();
    void SetFactory(ISymbolFactory& symbolFactory);
};
```

segment of my method:

```
void SymbolParser::SetupSymbolParser(ISymbolFactory& symbolFactory) {
    mSymbolFactory = symbolFactory;
    .....
}
```

maybe i have to mention that the constructor initialize the variable like this (and this is the object where i stuck at):

```
SymbolParser::SymbolParser() : mSymbolFactory(JavaFactory::GetInstance()) {}
```

Comment: You'll need to initialize `mSymbolFactory` from construction, that's the only way to assign it from another reference.

Comment: Object references in a class has to be assigned to a valid object in the constructor of the class

Comment: but i have to change it afterwards. so then i need a pointer?

Comment: If you have to change it later, you'll need a pointer yes.

Comment: @schreda

Yes, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pointer rather than a reference object if you want to be able assign to something else at runtime.

Do it like this:

```
class SymbolParser: public Object {
private:
    ISymbolFactory* mSymbolFactory;
public:
    SymbolParser();
    ~SymbolParser();
    void SetFactory(ISymbolFactory& symbolFactory);
};
```

In your segment:

```
void SymbolParser::SetupSymbolParser(ISymbolFactory& symbolFactory) {
    mSymbolFactory = &symbolFactory;
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Symbolparser(Symbolfactory& symbolFactory) :
>   mSymbolFactory(symbolFatory) {}

you can just initialize a refference in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead:

```
class SymbolParser: public Object {
private:
    ISymbolFactory& mSymbolFactory;
public:
    SymbolParser(ISymbolFactory& symbolFactory)
    : mSymbolFactory(symbolFactory) {}
    ~SymbolParser();
};
```